# Fixed background image for a div

Tags: html, css

I have created a image tile for which i have set a background image. But when i re-size the tile image on the background also gets re-sized, is there a way to make the background image stay to full image regardless of the tile size. The ratio doesn't matter. I only need the tile to display the full image.

```css
.activity-image {
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: auto;
  height: 210px;
  background-image: url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
.tile {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <div class="activity-image "></div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9hy3mcun/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `background-size: 100% 100%` instead. First value is `width` and second is `height` of background.

```css
 .activity-image {
   border-radius: 12px;
   width: auto;
   height: 210px;
   background-image: url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <div class="activity-image "></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `background-size: 100% 100%;`?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hy3mcun/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify min-width for activity-image and set .title to overflow:hidden.

```
 .activity-image{
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: auto;
    height: 210px;
    background-image: url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    min-width: 900px; 
  }

   .tile{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 12px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```